# Change Leaflet js map colors with vue js

Tags: vue.js, colors, leaflet

I need your help.
I've started a project using Vue.js and I'm trying to add Leaflet.js map and change the colors of the waters and continents.

My code:

```
<template>
  <div id="map">
    <l-map ref="map" :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import { LMap, LTileLayer } from 'vue2-leaflet';

export default {
   name: 'example',
   components: {
   LMap,
   LTileLayer
   },
   data () {
   return {
      zoom:2,
      center: L.latLng(20, 0),
   }
   },mounted() {
       window.dispatchEvent(new Event( 'resize', () => {
           this.$refs.map.mapObject.fitWorld( { animate: true } ).zoomIn()
       }))
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.fitWorld().zoomIn()
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.dragging.disable()
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.touchZoom.disable()
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.doubleClickZoom.disable()
        this.$refs.map.mapObject.scrollWheelZoom.disable()


this.$refs.map.mapObject.removeControl(this.$refs.map.mapObject.zoomControl)
       this.initMap()
    },methods:{
       initMap(){
           L.tileLayer(



    'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/dord/
    cjin79y8x0b762rmnv2pz4dft/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=###', {
              tileSize: 512,
          }).addTo(this.$refs.map.mapObject);
      }
     }
    }
   </script>
```

Please help me to change the colors and if u can explain me also.
Thanks/

Comment: It’s not the same

Comment: If you don't use vector layers, you can't change style client side (at least using raster tiles from Mapbox). If using vector tiles, you may use https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid